# Set activity as content in swipey tabs?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I found [this](https://github.com/astuetz/android-viewpagertabs)
 great example of the implementation of Swipey tabs (the tabs UI like in the Android Market).

Is it possible to set an activity as its content? Is there anything like an "Activity Container" that I can set up in the XML and put an activity in it? So basically I want to have multiple activities set as content in the `ViewPager`. Let me know if anyone has some good solution on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you are looking for are [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), but they are only available for Android SDK 3.0 and above.

---

EDIT: I was under the impression that an `Activity` could not be placed inside a `View`. Apparently I was wrong. [Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b61a126495cfcddc?pli=1) is an old thread about using a `LocalActivityManager` to place an activity inside a container view.

In case the thread disappears, the most useful post contains this code fragment:

```
void createInnerActivity(ViewGroup container, Class<?> activityClass) 
{ 
    if (container.getChildCount() != 0) { 
        container.removeViewAt(0); 
    } 
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass); 
    final Window window = 
        getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(activityClass.toString(), 
                                                intent); 
    container.addView(
        window.getDecorView(),
        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
}
```

Comment: I know that Fragments can be used on lower SDK by adding the android-compatibility Library. Ok, lets say it is fragments what Im looking for, can I put a fragment into each page and set an Activity as its content? Is that possible?

Comment: You could go the opposite way - add each fragment to both the pages, and to the activity you want to share the UI with. I am assuming you want to put activities in the pages in order to reuse them somewhere else. I didn't know about the compat lib. I will check it out, thanks. :)

Comment: Im not really following, sorry. Can you link me to some instruction on that? Im still a noob with android :/ Really appreciated.

Comment: Never mind. I was wrong about not being able to place activity inside a view. I am a beginner on Android myself. :)